# Is Object in dynamic link library(.dll) shared across process

Tags: c++, dll, multiprocessing, dynamic-linking

suppose i have two class and a .c file in my .dll file. such as

```
class MyClass {
private :
  int id;
  Context* appContext;
  static Context* statContext;
public:
a(){
    appContext = NULL;
    id = -1;
}
void setId(int a){ 
   id = a;
}
void setContext(){
    statContext = appContext = new Context();
}

Context* getContext(){
    return appContext;
}
Contex* getStaticContex(){
    return statContext;
}
int getId(){
   return id;
}
}

class Context{
Contex(){};
~Context(){};
}
```

In my .c file, there are three function those are exposed outside the .dll through dllexport which contain

```
MyClass a;
void dllSetContext(){
    a.SetContext();
}

Context* dllGetContext(){
    a.getContext();
 }

 Context* dllGetStaticContext(){
    a.getStaticContex();
 }
```

- Now one process after loading the dll calls dllSetContext();
- Another process also loads the dll and calls  dllGetContext() and 
  dllGetStaticContext(). Does it get the instance of **appContext**,
  **statContext** set by first Process?
- Is there two separate instance of **MyClass** created, each separate
  instance for each process
- Or those two processes share one single instance of MyClass?

My understanding here is static and global variables is not shared across Multiple process, but others are shared across multiple process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the operating system how the address space is managed. In modern (32 bit) Windows operating system you have an addres per process. There is nothing common between processes.

This is not different when an object is created in a DLL. You get different instances in different processes. But they might get the same virtual address. Keep in mind that the instance's address is only valid in the process where the DLL is loaded.

This might be different when you program for Windows 3.x, but I doubt that you do this.

*Edit* If and how the code segment is shared between processes can depend on the actual O/S. In WinCE 5.0 you have a shared process slot. If the DLL is located as a MODULE during sysgen, the code is in this shared slot visible to all processes same address range. You don't find this at desktop Windows.

In some O/S it's possible that the same code section is in the same *physical address* but is visible at a process dependent *virtual address*. But if you develop an application you don't need to think about it. The code is just visible an a process. The same DLL code can be located at different address when the DLL's load address is already occupied. In that case the O/S relocates the DLL to a free addrrss range. This takes ( a bit) time and can be tuned by setting a different default load address to each DLL.

Comment: Does that mean Object creation code is shared across process, not the object ? Is it same for WIN64, Unix system(linux, mac) with 32bits and upper? Thanks